# Real-world examples of rent-seeking games

Tags: game-theory, rent

In rent-seeking games, players use costly effort to compete for a reward. The objective function of player $i$ may be
\begin{align} 
\pi_i(x_i) = \frac{x_i}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j}R - c_ix_i, 
\end{align}
where $R$ is the reward, $x_i$ is the ``effort'' of player $i$, and $c_i$ is player $i$'s cost per unit effort. Players are rewarded based on their share of the total effort. For example, if player $i$ supplies 20% of the total effort, then player $i$ receives 20% of the reward.

Rent-seeking games are commonly used to model the competition for a government contract, or to model the lobbying to get access to a certain resource. However, these are generally theoretical situations for which data is not really available.

My question is: Are there any real-world rent-seeking games that can be used to test the implications of different rent-seeking models (e.g., different cost functions)?

One such application is in the so-called mining of cryptocurrencies, where ``miners'' use computer power to compete for newly issued cryptocurrency. The mining process is designed such that if miner $i$ supplies 20% of the computer power, then miner $i$ receives 20% of the reward. Here there is a clearly defined reward (the total reward allocated to miners), and there is a well-defined cost of effort (the cost of running specialized computers and hardware).

Are there other examples of well-defined rent-seeking games?

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a reference where this type of game is called "rent-seeking game"? I have not seen this before, though the game can be used to model some rent-seeking situations.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "*well-defined*"? Games where there is no uncertainty about the payoffs once the strategies are known?

Comment: @Giskard For an early reference you can see "Modelling rent-seeking contests" by Nitzan (1994). 

I should not have used the term "well-defined"; what I meant was a situation for which data can be collected to test the implications of rent-seeking models.